# Notepad Tutorial: Add baseadapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, baseadapter

I have done the notepad tutorial from android webside. I added an own Module-Class. Now I also want to add a own baseadapter. But I have problems with the implementation.

**My problem is the fillData() method.** It is in the third code part. I am also not sure, if I will need a cursor?

I hope anybody can help me, to correct the fillData() method.

**My Module-Class**

```
public class Module {
private String title;
private String device_type;
private String home_code;
private String device_code;

public Module(String n, String m, String hc, String mc) {
    title = n;
    device_type = m;
    home_code = hc;
    device_code = mc;
}

public String getTitle() { return title; }
public String getDeviceType() { return device_type; }
public String getHomeCode() { return home_code; }
public String getDeviceCode() { return device_code; }
```

}

**My Module Adapter:**

```
public class ModuleAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
private Context context;

private List<Module> listModule;

public ModuleAdapter(Context context, List<Module> listModule) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listModule = listModule;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listModule.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listModule.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Module entry = listModule.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_row, null);
    }
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    tvTitle.setText(entry.getTitle());

    TextView tvDeviceType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    tvDeviceType.setText(entry.getDeviceType());

    TextView tvHomeCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
    tvHomeCode.setText(entry.getHomeCode());

    TextView tvDeviceCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text4);
    tvDeviceCode.setText(entry.getDeviceCode());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Module entry = (Module) view.getTag();
    listModule.remove(entry);
    // listModule.remove(view.getId());
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private void showDialog(Module entry) {
    // Create and show your dialog
    // Depending on the Dialogs button clicks delete it or do nothing
}
```

}

**The fillData() method from the main code:**

```
    private void fillData() {
    //Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    //startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    final List<Module> from = new ArrayList<Module>();
    from.add(new Module(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DEVICETYPE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_HOMECODE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DEVICECODE));

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    //SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
    //    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
    //notes.setViewBinder(new ModuleViewBinder());

    ModuleAdapter adapter = new ModuleAdapter(this, from);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Felix

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem: are you only asking if you need a cursor in fillData? Or is there something specific that doesn't work or you don't know how to do?

Comment: I edited the code a little bit. My problem is, that the values from the db are not loaded. Only the key word: title, device_type, home_code are displayed. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, now it's clearer: please edit the question before people can answer, for example you don't even mention that you have values stored in a database.

Comment: Oh yes sorry. My database has a many values in it. Before I loaded the columns in the SimpleCursor Adapter. But now, it don't know how I load the columns of my databse in my base adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your data is in a database, so you should keep using the SimpleCursorAdapter as you were doing in the code you commented out.

Your new code puts a module filled in with the names of the database columns (and not the actual data) in the ArrayList:

```
from.add(new Module(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DEVICETYPE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_HOMECODE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DEVICECODE));
```

Then your custom adapter works correctly, because it displays those values.

What probably got you confused is that you were passing the same strings to the SimpleCursorAdapter, but that adapter uses the column names to fetch data from the database. Your custom adapter instead simply shows what's in the list.

If you want to show the values from the database you should stick to SimpleCursorAdapter (or extend it if you need to do more).

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to use the SimpleCursorAdapter. I want to use the BaseAdapter, because later on I also want to display buttons and icons in my listview.  Shouldn't it be possible to use the BaseAdapter with the database?

Comment: No, the right approach is to use the CursorAdapter with a database, and if you want to customise how the list looks then you write your own [ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) and write a custom layout for your cell.

Comment: Hmm. I've done this tutorial. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive At 6.2 the  guy is working with an ArrayAdapter<Model> and not a CursorAdapter. Because if this, I thought it is a good way to use the BaseAdapter for my case.

Comment: I looked at the tutorial: it works (and it's a good tutorial) because it's using Strings just to show how things work, it doesn't take data from a database until step 9, where in fact it says: "In case you work with a content provider or directly with the database you can use the SimpleCursorAdapter to define the data for your ListView. For more information on Android and SQLight please see the SQLite and Lists Tutorial".